# sum up data without specific key name

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

I am trying to summarise the values of a json file that does not have a a distinct Keyname.

The data looks something like this

```
"Bremen": {
    "Total": 212884,
    "BioNTech": 128435,
    "Moderna": 17210,
    "AstraZeneca": 67239
  },
  "Hamburg": {
    "Total": 530203,
    "BioNTech": 336368,
    "Moderna": 73308,
    "AstraZeneca": 120527
  },
  "Hessen": {
    "Total": 1853184,
    "BioNTech": 1166322,
    "Moderna": 218812,
    "AstraZeneca": 468050
  },
...
```

Now I'd like to aggregate all BioNTec values, Moderna Values, etc.

I thought about using d3.js rollout like this

```
var sumByName = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .entries(data);
```

But I do not understand how I can specify to use any given Key name instead of hardcoding the Name (d.name in my example), since my dataset does not have that.
Using Object.keys(d) did not work either.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done with `reduce`:

```
const aggregated = Object.values(data)
  .reduce((sum, item) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => sum[key] = item[key] + (sum[key] || 0));
    return sum;
  }, {});
```

```js
const data = {
  "Bremen": {
    "Gesamt": 212884,
    "BioNTech": 128435,
    "Moderna": 17210,
    "AstraZeneca": 67239
  },
  "Hamburg": {
    "Gesamt": 530203,
    "BioNTech": 336368,
    "Moderna": 73308,
    "AstraZeneca": 120527
  },
  "Hessen": {
    "Gesamt": 1853184,
    "BioNTech": 1166322,
    "Moderna": 218812,
    "AstraZeneca": 468050
  }
};

const aggregated = Object.values(data).reduce((sum, item) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => sum[key] = item[key] + (sum[key] || 0));
  return sum;
}, {});

console.log(aggregated);
```